# How plausible is this article on how SciHub acquires its papers?

Tags: attacks, attack-prevention

[Sci-Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub) is a piracy website that provides free access to usually-paywalled academic papers & books. Sci-Hub's owner Alexandra Elbakyan says that many people with legitimate access to the papers/books donate their user IDs and passwords, which she then uses to acquire the paywalled material.

Countering the owner's claim is [this article](https://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2018/09/18/guest-post-think-sci-hub-is-just-downloading-pdfs-think-again/) by Andrew Pitts, CEO of a cybersecurity firm. In the article, Andrew Pitts claims that Sci-Hub's user IDs and passwords are obtained illegally, via phishing, password cracking, hacking, and similar activities. It gives details that that look persuasive to me, but I lack the expertise to judge how credible the evidence is myself, and I was just told that the article provides no evidence and is written as an advertisement for getting the firm's help with security

Therefore I'm asking this question: does Andrew Pitts present a plausible case that Sci-Hub obtains user IDs and passwords via phishing, password cracking, etc? In other words, could the things he presents at evidence actually have happened? If no, why not?

Comment: In short: I can see no __independently__ verified material presented in what you link to. This means that one can count here only on the credibility of the author as a base for the claims. This does not implies that it is wrong, but it neither implies that it is correct. Apart from that: I think this question is primarily asking for opinions and not facts - which is off-topic here.

Comment: tl;dr no, it is not plausible (that technique could not possibly scale the way they claim)

Comment: While I don't think this question should have been closed as "opinion-based" (you can *objectively* adjudicate on an *opinion piece* such as that article), I do think that @SteffenUllrich is vaguely correct.

Comment: Specifically: that article describes **Iranian** cyberattacks in some detail, and then springboards from there to say (among other similar statements) “**We know that**, at one UK University, **Sci-Hub** managed to get six passwords through a 48-hour dictionary **attack on their system**.” (—*How* do we know that, Mr. Pitts? Because you dislike them, they're automatically implicated in every cyberattack on your clients?) The man describes uncontroversial `X`, then claims `Y`, without providing any evidence of the implicit `X→Y`. The article is **objectively implausible**.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this because the question is about the plausibility of this kind of attack, not whether or not the article is objectively true.

Comment: @forest the question as stated is _“does Andrew Pitts present a convincing case that **Sci-Hub obtains** user IDs and passwords via **\[hacking\]**? If so, which piece(s) of evidence cited is most persuasive? If not, why not?”_ — this is not about “the plausibility of this kind of attack” (phishing, password cracking, _etc._ are trivially plausible.); it's about the plausibility of Mr. Pitts' argument _per se_.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude The plausibility of the argument can be objectively analysis, although I think the last paragraph is worded in a way that makes it lean towards opinion-based in its current form.

Comment: And — back at the object-level — forget _“independent”_ verification: Mr. Pitts doesn't even present _any_ evidence implicating Sci-Hub. None. You don't even have to appeal to a potentially-subjective authority to tear apart his bizarre rant; it doesn't even _present_ a case for its core thesis. If ever a "judge a journalist" question had an objective answer… this is among them.

Comment: I changed the last paragraph, might be answerable now.

Comment: For context, Pitts’ article is published on *Scholarly Kitchen*, which is a corporate propaganda outlet of the scientific publishing industry. The obviously have a vested interest in maligning Sci-Hub, and they are widely regarded as unreliable and sometimes dishonest by researchers. Publishing outright lies wouldn’t be first for them.

Comment: I worked in the University sector at the time this came out and this article made the rounds and was even promoted by some police news outlets. Here's the problem *with the question*: is it plausible that unauthorised access to X was granted to Y as a result of hacking? Uh, yes. That premise certainly is plausible. The problem *with the article*: there is a screaming empty void of proof, or even connected dots, to implicate this particular site of any wrongdoing suggested in the article. The article has all the hallmarks of "a stitch-up". So, without proof or facts, conclusions are opinions.

Comment: The question: "does Andrew Pitts **present** a plausible case that SciHub [hacks]" has a trivial, objective answer: no he does *not*, and, in fact, he doesn't even present *a* case. Why was this closed as "opinion-based" when it can be answered properly and thoroughly without any recourse to opinion?